# build spring framework source code encounter an error

Tags: java, spring, git, gradle

I fetched the spring framework source code from github by using `git clone` command. When I build the source code by using `gradle build` in the source code directory,it takes a long time to download dependencies and compile the java code,but failed with an exception.The output is below.

```
:spring-webmvc-portlet:sourcesJar UP-TO-DATE
:spring-webmvc-tiles2:javadoc SKIPPED
:spring-webmvc-tiles2:javadocJar SKIPPED
:spring-webmvc-tiles2:sourcesJar SKIPPED
:spring-websocket:javadoc UP-TO-DATE
:spring-websocket:javadocJar UP-TO-DATE
:spring-websocket:sourcesJar UP-TO-DATE
:distZip

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'distZip' during up-to-date c
heck.  See stacktrace for details.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\yuqing\workspace\spring-framework\buil
d\distributions\spring-framework-4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT-schema.zip 

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to capture snapshot of input files f
or task 'distZip' during up-to-date check.  See stacktrace for details.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.TaskUpToDateState.<init
>(TaskUpToDateState.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactSt
ateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getStates(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository
.java:132)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactSt
ateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepositor
y.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.exec
ute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execut
e(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecu
ter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter
.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execut
e(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter
.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTa
skWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTa
skWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorW
orker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorW
orker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(Defaul
tTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(Defau
ltTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTask
ExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecute
r.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExec
uter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecu
ter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildEx
ecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecute
r.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecute
r.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLa
uncher.java:154)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(Default
GradleLauncher.java:151)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGra
dleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradl
eLauncher.java:99)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradl
eLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradle
Launcher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLaun
cher.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildCon
....
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C
:\Users\yuqing\workspace\spring-framework\build\distributions\spring-framework-4
.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT-schema.zip (系统找不到指定的文件。)
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.HashUtil.createHash(HashUtil.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.hash.DefaultHasher.hash(DefaultHasher.java:24
)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileSnapshotter.
snapshot(CachingFileSnapshotter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileSnapshotter.
snapshot(CachingFileSnapshotter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileSnapshotter.
snapshot(CachingFileSnapshotter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileCollectionSn
apshotter$1.run(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAcc
ess.java:192)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAcc
ess.java:175)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(De
faultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.
useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStat
eCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileCollectionSn
apshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.TaskUpToDateState.<init
>(TaskUpToDateState.java:56)
        ... 57 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\yuqing\workspace\spring-frame
work\build\distributions\spring-framework-4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT-schema.zip 
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.HashUtil.createHash(HashUtil.java:34)
        ... 70 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 20.861 secs
```

The error indicates the file `spring-framework-4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT-schema.zip` not found.I wondered why this file is not found,it should be created by `distZip` task but it doesn't.
I have googled this problem but not found any question about this.

Comment: It took *24 mins 50.967 secs* but succeeded.

Answer (score 3):

I have resovled this problem,the devil is path separator.Because this command runs on windows.
Modify schemaZip task definition from

```
task schemaZip(type: Zip) {
        group = "Distribution"
        baseName = "spring-framework"
        classifier = "schema"
        description = "Builds -${classifier} archive containing all " +
            "XSDs for deployment at http://springframework.org/schema."
        duplicatesStrategy 'exclude'
        moduleProjects.each { subproject ->
            def Properties schemas = new Properties();

            subproject.sourceSets.main.resources.find {
                it.path.endsWith("META-INF/spring.schemas")
            }?.withInputStream { schemas.load(it) }

            for (def key : schemas.keySet()) {
                def shortName = key.replaceAll(/http.*schema.(.*).spring-.*/, '$1')
                assert shortName != key
                File xsdFile = subproject.sourceSets.main.resources.find {
                    it.path.endsWith(schemas.get(key))
                }
                assert xsdFile != null
                into (shortName) {
                    from xsdFile.path
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

to

```
task schemaZip(type: Zip) {
        group = "Distribution"
        baseName = "spring-framework"
        classifier = "schema"
        description = "Builds -${classifier} archive containing all " +
            "XSDs for deployment at http://springframework.org/schema."
        duplicatesStrategy 'exclude'
        moduleProjects.each { subproject ->
            def Properties schemas = new Properties();

            subproject.sourceSets.main.resources.find {
                it.path.endsWith("META-INF\\spring.schemas")
            }?.withInputStream { schemas.load(it) }

            for (def key : schemas.keySet()) {
                def shortName = key.replaceAll(/http.*schema.(.*).spring-.*/, '$1')
                assert shortName != key
                File xsdFile = subproject.sourceSets.main.resources.find {
                    it.path.endsWith(schemas.get(key).replaceAll('\\/','\\\\'))
                }
                assert xsdFile != null
                into (shortName) {
                    from xsdFile.path
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you know nothing about gradle like me, the file is spring-framework/gradle/docs.gradle